# Error connecting express node.js app to redis server when using requirepass in redis.conf

Tags: node.js, redis, express

I'm new to node and redis and am setting up a simple server with express to communicate with redis.

After starting redis-server, I start the node server app.js

app.js starts and runs when I use the redis.conf file without requirepass, but when I add a requirepass the app crashes upon starting. I can run redis-cli in a terminal and the password works there.

I get this Uncaught error stack when running app.js:

```
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
    Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.
    at RedisClient.emit (events.js:47:15)
    at Command.callback (/node_modules/redis/index.js:232:29)
    at RedisClient.return_error (/node_modules/redis/index.js:382:25)
    at RedisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/node_modules/redis/index.js:78:14)
    at RedisReplyParser.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at RedisReplyParser.send_error (/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:265:14)
    at RedisReplyParser.execute (/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:124:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/node_modules/redis/index.js:358:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/redis/index.js:93:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
```

Here's the pertinent code in app.js

```
    var REDIS_PASS = "foobar";

    var express = require('express');
    var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
    var redis  = require('redis');
    var rdb = redis.createClient();
    rdb.auth(REDIS_PASS, function(){ console.log('connected to redis-server');});

    rdb.on("error",function(err){
    console.log("REDIS CLIENT ERROR:" + err + '\n\n' + err.stack);
    });
```

Here's the redis.conf file

```
    # Warning: since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to
    # 150k passwords per second against a good box. This means that you should
    # use a very strong password otherwise it will be very easy to break.
    #
    #my hackerproof password:
    requirepass foobar
```

I am still trying to get my head around the asynchronous nature of node, so I thought maybe this was a case where the auth command was being called before a connection to the redis-server was established, but when I placed the auth command into a callback for the client.on("connect" event I received the same error stack.

I wondered if catching the exception would allow the server to sweep it under the carpet and continue so I caught it using the process object. The server appears to continue running but won't serve any pages to the browser, so I'm guessing this exception can't be ignored.

Comment: Try to set up listener for the "error" event emitted by the redis client (it is mentioned in [API](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)) and see what it emits (and update the question with emitted output please).

Comment: I was looking at the node_redis documentation and noticed that CreateClient can take an options parameter. I edited my CreateClient like so:  

    var opts = {'auth_pass':true};
    var rdb = redis.createClient(6379,'127.0.0.1',opts); 

and now it seems to be working

Comment: On further inspection, I think the problem was caused by using connect-redis with my setup. When I commented it out and removed it from the app configuration the problem goes away even without adding the options parameter in the CreateClient call.

Comment: Thanks for the help yojimbo. I added the .on("error  but the server seems to crash before loggin the error to the console. I will update my posted code with the .on("error

Comment: My original intent was to use connect-redis for my sessions. Is it better to store session-ids using my redis client and leave connect-redis out of this setup?

Comment: It looks like the connect-redis object needs to be setup using my redis password as an option. I'm going to try that and update with the results.

Comment: I think you should use connect-redis for session management and custom redis connection to do your own stuff. This way you would have standalone connections which do not depend on each other. BTW you can write your solution as answer to your own question and mark it as accepted since you managed to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks yojimbo. I had to wait until my account was 6 hours old to post my answer. I will go with your advice and use the two separate connections.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was caused by configuring my app with a RedisStore object to handle sessions. After enabling the password in the redis.conf file, the RedisStore object needed to be created with the pass option set to the password in redis.conf.

The options array is set like this:

```
    var redisStoreOpts = {'pass':REDIS_PASS};
```

and the line in the app configuration is changed to look like this:

```
    app.use(express.session({ secret: SESSION_SECRET, store: new RedisStore(redisStoreOpts) }));
```

I hope this is useful to anybody who runs into this problem.